# Using Easy Google Fonts plugin to override theme header: How can I find the right selector?

Tags: wordpress, css

I'm using the theme which has inherited its' style from the theme Wallstreet for WordPress and I cannot find the selector to use with Google fonts plugin that will let me change the font face for the title in the header section.

I've looked at both the main stylesheet as well as the header, and I've yet to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=GOOGLEFONT">
<style>
  body {
    font-family: 'GOOGLEFONT', serif;
    font-size: 48px;
  }
</style>
```

In the headers of any webpage, calling like this would be common,
In wordpress its a bit different...
I would call in into play in the style sheet of the theme you are using by doing this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=GOOGLEFONT');
```

replacing GOOGLEFONT with the font of your own choosing

Comment: I'm looking for a CSS solution using class. I'm looking for someone who knows the class selector that was used to control the Wallstreet/Healing Touch slider text which is probably three different selectors, since the slider has three differently sized fonts on it. I need a dark font, and the font that is there is white. I would be able to change it using the google fonts plugin, if I had the correct selector.